# Web scraping returns merged sentences in R

Tags: r, csv, web-scraping, character

I've scraped some lyrics from the link https://www.vagalume.com.br/ivete-sangalo/. There, the lyrics are displayed as follows (just a snippet):

```
 Quando a chuva passar

 Pra quê falar 
 Se você não quer me ouvir?
 Fugir agora não resolve nada
```

As you see, each sentence is split in a new line. But when I scrape the lyrics and save them in a csv file, R returns merged sentences, as follows:

```
 Output:
 Quando a chuva passarPra quê falarSe você não quer me ouvir?Fugir agora não resolve nada
```

This is my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link <- "https://www.vagalume.com.br/ivete-sangalo/"

page <- read_html(link)

name_link_id <- page %>% html_nodes('.nameMusic') %>% html_attr("href")

name_link_full <-page %>% html_nodes('.nameMusic') %>% html_attr("href") %>%        
paste("https://www.vagalume.com.br", ., sep = "")

get_lyrics <- function(lyrics_link){

lyric <- read_html(lyrics_link)

all_lyrics <- lyric %>% html_nodes('#lyrics') %>% html_text() 
return(all_lyrics)
}

lyr <- sapply(name_link_full, FUN = get_lyrics)

lyrs <- data.frame(lyr, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

write.csv(lyrs, 'Ivete.Sangalo.csv')
```

I've tried `stringi()`, `strsplit()`, but nothing changes. Please, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function reads in the data and returns a data.frame with one column named `lyrics`.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

get_lyrics <- function(lyrics_link){
  lyrics_link %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes('#lyrics') %>% 
    html_text2() %>%
    gsub("\\n\\n", "\n", .) %>%
    str_split(pattern = "\\n") %>%
    unlist() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    `names<-`("lyrics")
}
link <- "https://www.vagalume.com.br/ivete-sangalo/"

page <- read_html(link)

name_link_full <- page %>% 
  html_nodes('.nameMusic') %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>%        
  paste("https://www.vagalume.com.br", ., sep = "")

lyr <- lapply(name_link_full[1:5], FUN = get_lyrics)
```

---

### Edit

Following the comments below, here are two ways of writing the lyrics to file.

First, `rbind` the vectors of list `lyr`. And remove the column header.

```
lyr <- lapply(name_link_full[1:5], FUN = get_lyrics)
lyrs <- lapply(lyr, \(l) paste(unlist(l),  collapse = " "))
lyrs <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lyrs)
names(lyrs) <- ''
```

Then, write as csv and as txt. The directory `"~/tmp"` is optional.

```
old_dir <- getwd()
setwd("~/tmp")
write.csv(lyrs, 'Ivete.Sangalo.csv', quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
writeLines(unlist(lyrs), con = 'Ivete.Sangalo.txt')
setwd(old_dir)
```

Comment: Hi, @RuiBarradas, olá. Thank you very much indeed for your kind answer. Unfortunatelly, it is still not working.

Comment: @CygnusX-1 What is the problem you are having? I works with me, what is not working with you?

Comment: Hi again, @RuiBarradas. Sorry, I think I wasn't explicit enough. It's just that each lyrics must remain in a single csv row and without and that name 'lyrics'. Just the plain lyrics.

Comment: @CygnusX-1 OK, how do you want the verses to be written, one lyrics per row but the verses separated by a space? If so, why the csv format? csv files have a column header, remove `"lyrics"` and replace by what?

Comment: @CygnusX-1 If you want one lyrics per row, why not a plain txt file, written with `writeLines`?

Comment: Hi, @RuiBarradas. Thank you very much for your patience. The link "ivete sangalo", is one of many singers in the Axé folder at the webpage. I dont know how to loop through all of them, split each song in folders with the name of the singer, so I'm going one by one. Then move to the next style MPB, FUNK, etc and do the same thing. Then I still need to figure out a way to split the csv into txt files for each of them. That code I wrote took me three days, I am not a programmer. If I had asked this whole question here, people would have kicked me out. Anyway, I accept your answer! Thank you!